# Replace substrings with object property using flag character

Tags: string, excel, substring, vba

I need to replace generic substrings marked with a flag character with specific values from a custom object.  I have written the code that accomplishes what I want, though it feels awkward.  I'm wondering if there is a more sophisticated solution to this issue.  Specifically, I'm wondering if there is a quick function to replace so-marked substrings with other values, dependent on the generically occurring substring.

Here's my current code:

```
Private Function DeGenerify(field_text As String)
    Dim new_text As String, breakup As Variant
    Dim i As Integer, lgth As Integer, prop As String
    new_text = ""
    breakup = Split(field_text)
    For i = 0 To UBound(breakup)
        If left(breakup(i), 1) = "$" Then
            lgth = Len(breakup(i)) - 1
            prop = right(breakup(i), lgth)
            breakup(i) = CallByName(CFAL, prop, VbGet)
        End If
        new_text = new_text & breakup(i) & " "
    Next i
    DeGenerify = Trim(new_text) & "."
End Function
```

This has the desired effect, that of replacing all words in the string beginning with the "$" with the corresponding property of the "CFAL" object, provided it is a string.  For example, the text:

> All $STATION Fuel is class $F_CLASS consistent with T.S. $C_FlTbl

is replaced with the text:

> All Millstone 2 Fuel is class CE14x14 consistent with T.S. Tables
>   1-1e & 1-1f.

It seems as though a function must already exist to grab those $xxxx fields and replace them, without me having to split the string up and do so one by one.

Is anyone aware of such a thing?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to pull out all of the tokens and use Replace() to substitute in the values.

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeGenerifyTester()
    Debug.Print DeGenerify("All $STATION Fuel is class $F_CLASS" & _
                           " consistent with T.S. $C_FlTbl", CFAL)
    '>>> All STATION_value Fuel is class F_CLASS_value consistent with T.S. C_FlTbl_value
End Sub



Private Function DeGenerify(field_text As String, obj As Object)

    Dim col, v, rv, prop
    Set col = ExtractTokens(field_text)
    rv = field_text

    For Each v In col
        Debug.Print "-->", v
        prop = Replace(v, "$", "")
        'rv = Replace(rv, v, prop & "_value") '<< for testing...
        rv = replace(rv, v, CallByName(obj, prop, VbGet))
    Next v

    DeGenerify = rv

End Function


Function ExtractTokens(ByVal text As String) As Collection

    Dim result As New Collection
    Dim allMatches As Object, m As Object
    Dim RE As Object
    Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    RE.Pattern = "(\$[\w_]+)"
    RE.Global = True
    RE.IgnoreCase = True
    Set allMatches = RE.Execute(text)

    For Each m In allMatches
        result.Add m
    Next m

    Set ExtractTokens = result

End Function
```

VBScript regular expressions:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx